# How to send received Bluetooth data from a main activity to two fragments?

Tags: android

I am an Android beginner and comes from the micro-controller world. I want to write an app to display my Bluetooth data (the Bluetooth part is already working and I could display my characteristics via notification!).

Now I want to display the received values in two different fragments:

Fragment1: to display a graphic of the last 5 minutes.

Fragment2: to display the latest value in the text

The swiping between the fragments works fine, but I am not sure how to send my received data to the fragments. Maybe a bundle?

Comment: Could you add your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Java class and name it as DataHolder. Define its variables, getter & setter methods as static. When you received data, set the values using set method. when you want to get values, use get method. Its simple java. Best thing is you can get and set data from any activity or any fragment using this method.

```
public class DataHolder {
    private static String Data="";

    public static void set_Data(String s){
        DataHolder.Data = s;
    }

    public static String get_Data(){
        return DataHolder.Data;
    }
}
```

To set values to the DataHolder class use.

```
String BluetoothData=""; //get Bluetooth data to this variable
DataHolder.set_Data(BluetoothData);
```

To get values from DataHolder class use.

```
String BluetoothData = DataHolder.get_Data();
```

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot. I Will try it.

Comment: You are welcome. If any problem occur, comment here. I can help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a [Broadcast](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) to send the data and register both fragments to that.